# SQL Server database users when applications share the same database

Tags: sql, sql-server

First English is not my native language, so this question can be answered somewhere else or may be duplicated, i tried to Google it, but i didn't find the proper way to describe my need so thank you for understanding.

i have two application (Server/Clients), The database is in the Server machine, and the Client application will just connect to the Database using Sql Server, I'm using EF, my question :

when i wanted to add Data Server, in the wizard it asks for SQL Authentication user :

[image]

I'm not sure, but i don't think i should use the "sa" account right !? can somebody confirm that to me please, and suggest me the right approach to do that ! thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, never use SA. Make a user for the server to use and givce it the needed rights. It is quite normal to have application specific logins on a database server.

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted to know, i have many Tables (for example A and B, and i need the Server application to access to both A and B, but the client application just the B Table) so how do i do that ? (You said : Make a user for the server to use... can you please give me a link to a good article on how to do that) Thank you so much.

Comment: Read the documentation, make 2 users, grand both users only the rights they need. Books online - SHOULD be installed on your computer.

Comment: http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/ht/Creating-A-Sql-Server-2008-Database-Account.htm